# An infinite loop in x86-64 assembler

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  long i, max;
  long sum = 0;
  max = (long)pow(2,32);

  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    sum += i; 
  }
  printf("%ld\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

`$gcc -S main.c`

The question is: In the `.L2` code below, `-8(%rbp)` always equals zero, and the `%rax` is always greater than zero. So this is a infinite loop? And if I compile with `gcc -S -O1 main.c`, it is very clear. I am really troubled!

Just a little part of the assembler code:

```
main:   
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -36(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -48(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $2, -4(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -24(%rbp)
    jmp .L2

.L3:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    addq    $1, -24(%rbp)

.L2:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax     
    cmpq    -8(%rbp), %rax       
    jl  .L3                      

.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
```

Comment: What is the size of a `long`? If it's 32 bits (4 bytes) then `pow(2, 32)` will overflow. It you want the max value a `long` can be, then you should use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) in C++, and `LONG_MAX` from the `<limits.h>` header file in C.

Comment: `-8(%rbp)` is the value `max` so it clearly shouldn't be zero. Maybe you could show more of the assembler where it gets set.

Comment: How many bytes did you read from -8(%rbp) when you checked that it's zero? It's value should be `0x100000000` which has zero in its lower 32 bits.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Pileborg sorry for not clearly clarify, I use **ubuntu 12.04 x86_64**. So the size of `long` is 8 bytes,then pow(2,32) will not overflow.

Comment: @mbratch but the `-8(%rbp)` is initialized to zero. and the first time of `cmpq -8(%rbx), %rax` is true, then always true.

Answer (score 2):

The real loop counter (`i`) is at `-24(%rbp)`. On the third line, it's increased. On the 4th line, it's loaded into `rax`. So `rax` is not a constant zero, it runs through values along with `i`.

`-8(%rbp)`, one assumes, is where `max` is. So the value of `i` is compared to that, and this is your loop exit condition. `-8(%rbp)` should not be zero. If it is, I smell rogue 32-bit arithmetic.

EDIT: I think I know what's the matter. Constants 2 and 32 are `int`, not `long`, therefore assumed to be 32-bit. Size of `int` is platform dependent; even GCC's convention might vary. `pow(int, int)` is implemented as as intrinsic. 2^32 is 0 when arguments are 32-bit.

Replace

```
max = (long)pow(2,32);
```

with

```
max = pow(2l, 32l);
```

Or better with with a constant:

```
max = 0x100000000l;
```

Like I and others suspected, there was a piece of 32-bitness in the mix.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not infinite loop. First of all %rax is not always greater than 0, in that line it gets value from -24(%rbp) which is obviously variable `i`. When it enters the loop it sets -24(%rbp) to zero and then jumps to .L2 It happens in part that you did not show. If -8(%rbp) which is value of variable of `max` is equal to zero (in case of overflow) `jl` will not jump to .L3 and loop will terminate after first check.
I do not quite understand why you need to read assembly for that, that's pretty obvious from C++ source code.

Comment: Also, from running the code, we can see that it ends. Even just a few extra `printf()` statements must help.

Comment: no, the `-8(%rbx)` is initialized to zero above which I have added extra codes. and the first time of `cmpq -8(%rbx), %rax` is true, then always true, unless `%rax` would overflow.

Comment: yeah, I just want to see the assembler's differences of the code compiled with `-O1` or not.Beacause i have found the code compiled with `-O1` spend so little time than the normally.

Comment: @xuefu as I said before `-24(%rbp)` is initialized to 0. Then it jumps to `.L2` then compares `-8(%rbp)` and `-24(%rbp)`, as they are both equal to 0 `jl` will not jump to .L3 so loop exits. Which part you do not understand?